# String cast vs String unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to compare string values. String values are stored in Dictionary.
When I unwrap data like this:

```
let type:String = basicBlk["type"] as! String
```

and compare

`print (type.lowercaseString == "minion")`
result is **true**

While if I cast like this:

```
let type:String = String(basicBlk["type"])
```

and compare

`print (type.lowercaseString == "minion")`
result is **false**

I would like to understand what exactly is the difference.

Comment: Which XCode version do you use?  Your code does not compile in my XCode 7.1.

Comment: @Anton it Xcode 7.1. basicBlk is Dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
let type:String = String(basicBlk["type"])
```

Converts the optional value into a string that looks like:

```
Optional("Minion")
```

And when you convert that string to lower case, it looks like:

```
optional("minion")
```

The issue is that you're creating a string representation of an optional value, and it's including the string "`Optional(`" and string "`)`" in the resulting value.

Just print `type` for both of your two examples and you'll see what I mean.